# Selenium find_element_by_xpath not working for instagram

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape Instagram using Python and Selenium. I have had many issues regarding locating the elements but somehow managed to pull through when I tried enough xpaths. But when I try to web scrape Donald Trump's following list (I want this to work for ANY USER'S `following` list/page), it just doesn't work. Here is the error it's throwing:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="f3b066159b38864"]/div/div/a"}
```

I get the xpaths by right clicking on the element using Google Chrome's inspect feature. If anyone needs me to post the full code I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: check if your id is dynamic

Comment: @DipakBachhav How can I do that. And if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: provide HTML or url ?

Comment: Here is the url. I cannot enter the ```Following``` page so you'll have to do it yourself ```https://www.instagram.com/realdonaldtrump/``` @DipakBachhav

Comment: @DipakBachhav Here is the line of HTML ```<a class="FPmhX notranslate  _0imsa " title="laraleatrump" href="/laraleatrump/">laraleatrump</a>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below xpath::

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'laraleatrump')]")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Working solution :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/realdonaldtrump/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'following')]"))).click()

peoples =  wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='dialog']//div[contains(@class,'PZuss')]//a")))

        for peoplename in peoples:
            print peoplename.text
```

Comment: I want the program to work with other users, so the part ```//a[contains(text(), 'laraleatrump')]``` wont work. What should I do?

Comment: What do you want exactly, Sorry without proper information cant provide you solution, would be useful if you provide more details and what you hhave tried

Comment: I want to be able to change the link to ```https://www.instagram.com/nike``` for example and for it to still work

Comment: Check solution so even if you changed your url you will get list of people

Comment: I just have one more question. What is the role attribute in HTML and where can I see an elements role in the Google Chrome inspect? Also where did you see the class 'PZuss'?

Comment: it's present on a dialog box when you click on a following link ,would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your end if your issue is resolved

Comment: What do you mean its present on a dialog box; how does that matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212448/discussion-between-dipak-bachhav-and-serket).